# Unity Touch Position difference is always positive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the following code for measuring the swipes on touch devices. However, the calculations I'm doing for moveHorizontal and moveVertical are always positive. The touch.position difference is always positive. The Player only moves in the top-right corner no matter if you're swiping or just long pressing the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            firstPos = new Vector2(touch.position.x / (float)Screen.width, touch.position.y / (float)Screen.width);
            lastPos = new Vector2(touch.position.x / (float)Screen.width, touch.position.y / (float)Screen.width);
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            lastPos = new Vector2(touch.position.x / (float)Screen.width, touch.position.y / (float)Screen.width);
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            lastPos = new Vector2(touch.position.x / (float)Screen.width, touch.position.y / (float)Screen.width);
        }
        moveHorizontal = lastPos.x - firstPos.x;
        moveVertical = lastPos.y - firstPos.y;
    }
}
```

I am using the following code to move the player object.

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
rigidbody.AddForce(movement * speed);
```

Comment: why do you `/ (float)Screen.width` everything? Could you add the code of how you are using the `moveXY` values?

Comment: I am dividing the touch position by screen width so the movements are proportioned to the screen width. I added the code to show how I'm using the moveHorizontal and moveVertical values.

Comment: shouldnt you use height instead of width for the y?

Comment: @Matriac I want them both to behave in the same proportion. Either height or width. I chose width since its the smaller one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the situation by trying to work out the input deltas on your own when you could just use touch.deltaPosition.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html

So you would do something like this

```
Vector2 movementVector;

foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    movementVector += touch.deltaPosition;
}

rigidbody.AddForce(speed * new Vector3(movementVector.x,0,movementVector.y));
```

Other notes: No need to check for the number of touches, the foreach wont do anything if there are no touches. Also, maybe you want to set the velocity directly instead of applying force, depends on the feel you want in the game.

Comment: I'm checking the number of touches to see if the device is a touch screen or if there's keyboard input available. Is there a better way to do it?